# Running an application on an os designed and created in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, embedded, windows-ce

I have built an os design (and its bsp) in Visual Studio. I need to know how to get started with writing applications for the os by writing a simple application that will run in the os created (probably in an emulator, I still don't have the Evaluation module for the device). I have Visual Studio 2005 and Windows embedded C.E. 6.0 installed.

Some blogs described how to create the application in eMbedded Visual C++. Will I have to install this apart from Visual Studio to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you built an image from an OSDesign for a specific device you cannot run it in the emulator. The emulator has it's own sepcific BSP based on which you need to create an OSdesign.

To develop an application for your osdesgin of choice open VS2005 create a new project of type `Visual C++-> Smart Device` and choose the type you want. Alternatively, you can create a C# application for smart devices that will run on any device that includes the `Compact Framework` component in the OSDesign or has it installed on the device.

You do not need additional software other than VS2005.

You can download a package from [this vendor](http://compulab.co.il/x300/download/release/x300-wince6-img-release.zip). It includes demo applications for Windows CE6 (for that device). It also includes a document of how to create a new application for the device. You can use the instructions to create an applcation to your own device.

To test your application as it will perform on the image you built, you will need a physical device.

**Update:** During the New Project wizard you will be asked to choose the designated platform (native projcets at least) and you will need to choose from a list of SDKs. The list shows the installed SDKs on your desktop machine. You can create your own SDK, but in order ofr it to show in that list you need to install it on the Machine. In Windows CE the SDKs are installed to: *C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce600*

Comment: Thanks a lot!
However, after choosing to create a smart device application, I need to specify which SDK is to be used. Although I tried to build an SDK for my OS, it doesn't show up in the list of available SDKs for the new application. The package mentioned in the answer has an SDK with it.