# create and run applications on an evaluation module using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I have built a BSP and OS Design in Visual Studio. I brought it up on the evaluation module, that is, I flashed the image to the EVM. I now need to develop applications that will run on the evaluation module. Do I do this by creating projects that are smart devices or by creating subprojects in the initial os design solution. I tried creating a subproject in the design solution, added a simple “Hello World..cpp” that compiled and ran perfectly earlier but now gives the error “cannot find “afxwin.h” ”. Basically, please tell me how to create and run applications on the evaluation module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have 2 options as you saw:**

1. Create a subproject in the OSDesign.
2. Create a deployable application in another instance of VS200#

The downside of the first method is that you need to deploy the whole image to the device every-time your application changes. There are ways to bypass part of the process, but the whole idea is cumbersome.

Using the second method is better because you will have an easier time to debug the application as well as deploy it faster.

**Steps to create an application with VS2005:**

1. If you develop in native code, you need to create an SDK for your OSDesign and install it on the development machine.
2. Create a smart device project in VS2005.
3. Choose your SDK in the wizard (platforms dialog)
4. Develop your application
5. Deploy it and debug it.

---

- You can look at [this](http://compulab.co.il/workspace/mediawiki/index.php5?title=WinCE:_Application_Development) tutorial for a step by step explanation with screen-shots.
- The answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205215/running-an-application-on-an-os-designed-and-created-in-visual-studio) is relevant with the evaluation board as well